# Maven CAS and restfullapi

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cas

I have a CAS installation adding restfullapi. I put in CAS web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.noelios.restlet.ext.spring.RestletFrameworkServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

create the restlet-servlet.xml file
and put in CAS pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-integration-restlet</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Now Eclipse show me errors about missing artifacts:

```
com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.jar:1.1.1
com.noelios.restlet.ext.spting.jar:1.1.1
org.restlet.jar:1.1.1
org.restlet.spring.jar:1.1.1
```

I have an .m2 settings file with a nexus repository. I put:

```
    <mirrors>
     <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      ...(allready configured mirror)
     </mirror>
     <mirror>
      <id>maven-restlet</id>
      <mirrorOf>com.noelios,org.restlet</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
     </mirror>
    </mirrors>
       <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>maven-restlet</id>
          <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
          <url>http://maven.restlet.org/</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

How can I add the http://maven.restlet.org repository to my CAS project and remove these errors?

Comment: Have you googled?

Comment: yes I did. The example I find show only a clear repository (not adding a new) and I arrive to a point where in .m2 directory are created but jar files are not downloaded (and so have missing artifacts).

Comment: Then Show how you have added the repository

Comment: added settings.xml

Answer (score 1):

You should add these maven dependencies to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.noelios.restlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.noelios.restlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.noelios.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```